# Manual suspension and afterwards

Tags: support, account-suspension

Will I be able to post questions again after suspension ends?

Before I got manually suspended, I was able to post questions.

Now I get "we are no longer accepting questions from this account"

Comment: What site are you getting this on?

Comment: @Oded Looks like it's SF that he's suspended on: http://serverfault.com/users/192756/sndlt

Comment: serverfault sir

Comment: @SndLt - yeah, just saw that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post ban is calculated *when you attempt to submit a question*.  If, at that time, it determines that your total contributions are sufficiently problematic as to merit a post ban, it won't let you ask the question.

The exact formula isn't public, but as far as I know (and I don't know for sure, and SE may or may not choose to comment publicly on this) a manual suspension isn't taken into consideration by the post ban formula.  That said, if you've gotten downvotes, had posts closed, had posts deleted, etc. during your suspension then it's possible for those actions to have pushed you below the threshold.

So, in short, it could go either way.  But as far as I know you won't be post banned *because* of a manual suspension that has ended, even if you coincidentally end up post banned by the time the suspension ends.

Comment: Before I was manually suspended, I was able to post questions again. Would that be back when manual suspension ends?

Comment: @SndLt Yes, I saw that.  My answer takes that into consideration.  You may, or may not, be banned when the suspension ends.  You (as far as I know) won't be banned *because* of the suspension though.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers. So you don't know for sure, I see.

Comment: By the way, who are SE?

Comment: @SndLt Stack Exchange.

Comment: So if I am not able to post questions in 7 days, what can I do? Just get more answers accepted?

Comment: @SndLt Improve the quality of your contributions to the site.